# java regex/arraylist issue, unable to get matches/arraylist store new values

Tags: java, android, regex, arraylist

just getting into java arrays and regex and trying to build a program I once previously built in php, what I need to happen is I have an arraylist from twitter that I would like to use regular expressions to find text containing links, if a text contains links I want to add these new values to a new array which I would like to display, however the final array returns empty, meaning that at some point either the regular expression in my code isnt matching properly or the values arent transferring over to the new array, as I am new to this in java I am unable to spot where this is going wrong, any help would be massive, thanks in advance.

```
protected void onPostExecute(ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(results);
        ArrayList<twitter4j.Status> al = new ArrayList<twitter4j.Status>();

        for(twitter4j.Status statii: results){

            String patternStr = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(statii.getText());
            if(matcher.find() == true){
                al.add(statii); 
            }
        }

        StatusListAdapter adapter = new StatusListAdapter(
                TweepicsappActivity.this, al);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: No need for `matcher.find() == true` simple `matcher.find()` will work.

Comment: interesting, however Im still not able to catch anything in the new array, I purposely set up the results to all include links in the text but what Ive done here still seems to be flawed, could my regex be off perhaps?

Comment: I can't solve that issue for you - but I do recommend moving the regex logic to the `doInBackground( ... )` thread and just returning the `ArrayList<twitter4j.Status>` to the `onPostExecute( ... )` because, as the javadoc shows (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)), `onPostExecute( ... )` is run on the UIThread...

Comment: android crashes in the later versions if you run a network task on the ui thread but for regular java operations its ok, seems like the issue was actually my regular expression pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex has a bunch of unescaped special-characters in it (i.e. things like `+` and `,` and `.` and `:` and `|` that have meaning to the regex parser and do not match literal text unless you escape them).

Personally I always escape all special characters in a regex, even for ones that have no special meaning to the regex parser.  The issues caused by forgetting to escape one can be too confusing to debug for it to be worth risking not escaping something, in my opinion.

So I would do `patternStr` like:

```
String patternStr = "(https?|ftp|file)\\://[\\-a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\&\\@\\#/\\%\\?\\=\\~\\_\\|\\!\\:\\,\\.\\;]*[\\-a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\&\\@\\#/\\%\\=\\~\\_\\|]";
```

Not very pretty, but it gets the job done.

Here's an example:  http://ideone.com/W8s3p

Comment: That's not correct.  If he is trying to match . (dot), for example, he needs to escape it \. but I don't see anything in his regex that is not part of the actual pattern.

Comment: this new regular expression worked great! however I would like to also do another more specifc match in php I was able to simply do a string pattern like this to find more specific regular expressions however this doesnt work in java is there a java equivalent to this? $hosts2  = "bit.ly|t.co"; $regex = "~http://($hosts)~"

Answer (score 0):

First, I would double check your regex.  Step through the code in the debugger.  Second, I would use matcher.matches() rather than find().  Lastly, if performance is important, I would reuse both the Matcher -- initializing it as a static member in a static class initializer.

```
private static final Matcher matcher;

static {
   String patternStr = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
   matcher = pattern.matcher("");
}

protected void onPostExecute(ResponseList results) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(results);
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    for(twitter4j.Status statii: results) {
        matcher.reset(statii.getText());
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            al.add(statii); 
        }
    }

    StatusListAdapter adapter = new StatusListAdapter(TweepicsappActivity.this, al);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```